# Relationship between eigenvalues of a matrix and its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is there any relationship between the derivative of a matrix which depend by a parameter and its eigenvalues?

Comment: Take the matrix $A(t)=(a)$  with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, than its derivative in respect to $t$ is obviously zero, and the eigenvalue of the matrix is $a$, so there is no relationship

Comment: I'm searching for a result which connect the definite positiveness of the matrix derivative with its eigenvalues.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the derivative, or the eigenvalues of the original matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues will be a function of the parameter too and you can write down the differential equations that govern their motion as a function of that parameter. You might want to look at:
Section III: Dynamics of eigenvalues in
http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4113
Best,
Ramis